# cat: not found when I execute ksh script

Tags: shell, unix

I have written the below code for one the requirement in UNIX shell scripting with generate_vendor_info.ksh name.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

sqlplus -s tips/tips@tipstest<< EOS

SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 135
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET WRAP OFF
SET MARKUP HTML OFF SPOOL OFF

spool vendor_info.dat
select 'B','|',to_char(sysdate,'YYYYDDMM') from dual;
select 'H','|',vendor_id,'|', case config_code when 'DASN' then 'ASNVENDOR' when 'VASN' then 'VCDVENDOR' END,'|', case config_value when 'Y' then 'Y' when 'N' then 'N' END,'|',to_char(updated_date,'YYYYDDMMHH24MISS') from tips_vendor_config_msi,dual where updated_date >= sysdate-19 and (config_code in ('DASN','VASN')) order by updated_date desc; 
select 'E','|',ltrim(count(*)+2) from tips_vendor_config_msi,dual where updated_date >= sysdate-19 and (config_code in ('DASN','VASN'));
spool off;

spool store_info.lst
select distinct(ltrim(s.store)) from tips_store_config_msi s where s.store='3753' order by s.store;
spool off;

EOS

TIMESTAMP=`date +"%C%y%m%d%H%M%S"`

for StoreNO in `cat store_info.lst`
  do
       FILENAME="$(echo ${StoreNO}.${TIMESTAMP})"
       ORIGINAL_FILE="vendor_info.dat"
       NEW_FILE="$(echo ${ORIGINAL_FILE}.${FILENAME})"
       cp $ORIGINAL_FILE $NEW_FILE
       echo $NEW_FILE       
done
```

---

When i execute the shell script i am getting the result as below.

```
TIPSTAPP (TIPS):/home/applprod/TMS/ASN/SCRIPTS:ksh generate_vendor_info.ksh       
[YOU HAVE NEW MAIL]
B|20142608
H|79790|VCDVENDOR|Y|20141008231111
H|79790|ASNVENDOR|N|20141008231111
H|79818|VCDVENDOR|Y|20140908231111
H|79818|ASNVENDOR|N|20140908231111
E|6
3753
**generate_vendor_info.ksh[33]: cat:  not found**
```

Comment: I think `cat` can't find the file `store_info.lst`? Are you sure it's created in this directory? Are you sure your SQL script creates that file at all?

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to indicate that your shell script is unable to find the `cat` command.

To debug this, run your ksh in verbose debugging mode, with the command `ksh -xv generate_vendor_info.ksh`.

Also, is there a reason that you are calling unnecessary `echo` commands in unnecessary subshells? You wrote `FILENAME="$(echo ${StoreNO}.${TIMESTAMP})"`, but this could much more simply be expressed as `FILENAME="${StoreNO}.${TIMESTAMP}"`, and the same two lines further on where you set `NEW_FILE`.